# How to handle redirect request in react to download file on browser.

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, cors

I am new to react & JS. Please help me out in solving below problem.

**Scenario**: I am getting a `SEE_OTHER` type of response from the backend which contains a URL of the file, I need to download that file on browser.

Response from the backend is something like :

```
 { status:"SEE_OTHER" 
        context: {
          ...
          ...
          headers: 
               Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ["GET, POST, DELETE, PUT"]
               Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ["*"]
               Location:[url from where file is to be downloaded]
         .....
        }   
 }
```

I'm trying to download the file after extracting URL from the response and execute below function below:

```
 async download(url) {
    let res = await fetch(URL.format(url));

    if(res.status >= 400) {
      throw Error(`HTTP error: ${res.status}`);
    }
    if(res.status === 200) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       window.location.href = res.url;
     }, 100);
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting below error on browser console.

> Failed to load
>   'www.xyz.com/abc.json'
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Above code works if I use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) on chrome. But what is a permanent solution for this problem.

Also, is there any way I could download file directly from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using express use the following package in your backend service to solve the issue.

https://github.com/expressjs/cors

The issue is because browsers by default prevent cross origin/domain access for few security reasons. Please refer the following link,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Resolved this by adding an Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response header from the requested resource server. Links provided above helped to know the key concept of CORS. thanks.