# CORS request, Content-Type: application/json

Tags: reactjs, cors

I am working on a web app with a React front end and a node back end. They are both running on my local computer, on `localhost:3000` and `localhost:8080` respectively. Is it possible to make a CORS request using `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }`?  Based on looking at other questions it seems to be, but I am still getting the error in the console:

`Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/chordSheets/0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

My code is:
React Component

```
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/chordSheets/${id}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      mode: 'cors',
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
```

Node settings:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Options");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  req.login = promisify(req.login, req);
  next();
});
```

If I understand things correctly this should allow the CORS request with `"Content-Type": "application/json"`  I don't understand why the console error is saying `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'` when it is set to `localhost:3000`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try simply `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '127.0.0.1'`

Comment: Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793613/how-to-handle-redirect-request-in-react-to-download-file-on-browser/48793680#48793680

Comment: Do you have some CORS browser extension installed? Can you reproduce the problem with all extensions disabled, or in Incognito/Private browsing mode, or in a different browser?

Answer (score -1):

This error is triggered by the browser. Cannot be fixed by tweaking client app code. To fix this you have to get your node server to handle the OPTIONS preflight request which is trigged by the browser when you make an ajax request to a different origin than the webpage is currently running on.

The server then needs to respond to this with the correct headers:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` or `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000'`

You can add this package to your node server: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

This will do all the heavy lifting for you.

If it just for development purposes you can just run chrome with web security disabled:

Mac: `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""`

Windows: `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I looks like I already have that CORS package installed. I was able to reproduce the problem in Firefox with no extensions or anything installed.  This is a weird one.